# Selectively disable i2c on Rasbian Buster

Tags: raspbian, gpio, i2c, compute-module-3

I want to disable i2c0 while keeping i2c1 active.

Everything I can find either disables or enables both, but I haven't found a way to only activate one of them.

Comment: I saw a reference to dtparam=i2c1=on but cannot find the post now (not on the same computer) and I’m not sure how old this was.  Gut feel is it will be buried in the device tree which is way over my skill level / pay grade :-). I also thought I2C0 was HAT eeprom only and not supposed to be used for ANYTHING...

Comment: I am using a Compute Module 3, which does not really have a concept of hats, but instead just provides i2c0 as regular i2c pins.

Comment: Many graphics of the Pi 4 GPIO connector pinout label pin 28 as GPIO 1.  Are these all just WRONG? other graphics indicate reserved, as per user115418's suggestion

Comment: @plasmo Doesn't really have anything to do with this question, but checkout the official schematic here: https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-reduced-schematics.pdf and the official documentation here: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html

Comment: @plasmo They both say that pins 27 and 28 are used as an I²C interface by default, which is used to auto-detect hats. If you disable I²C, you can use them as GPIO 0 and 1, but then the hat autodetection feature is gone. So no, none of these graphics are wrong. The pins are both I²C/Hat autodetection and GPIO 0/1. Depending on how they are configured.

Comment: How do you disable I2C?  I was unable to determine how to do this for i2c0.

Comment: @plasmo `sudo raspi-config` -> `Interface Options` -> `I2C` -> `No`

Comment: cf @Dakkaron  Even though I have done the raspi-config thing to disable I2C altogether, these pins 27 and 28 still cannot be assigned as GPIO. You could test this before posting the obvious solution. By the way, the schematic you linked to has a note indicating "Do not use these pins for anything other than attaching an I2C ID EEPROM."  My question is still: is there any (other) way to used them as GPIO 0 and 1, or are ALL the graphics that indicate this WRONG.

Comment: @plasmo You could google yourself or start your own question instead or highjacking the obviously wrong question. I don't really care about your issue. Being impolite while not following the SE rules won't help you get an answer. Also, this is YOUR problem. Why should I test stuff for you?